# Keep last parameter from one task to the other in inkscape

Tags: inkscape, save, configuration

I am using Inkscape for scientific drawing.

Something that really annoys me is that I have to very frequently go in the menu to switch default parameters to the one I want to use.

For instance, the default width for line drawing is 0.265mm.

Let's assume I want to draw a line (with Bézier tool) of 1.5mm of width. I put 1.5mm width, I draw my line: this is fine it is the first drawing.

But if I want to draw a new line, by default he would have put be back at 0.265mm. Thus, I have **again** to go in the menu, say I want 1.5mm and draw it.

*Multiply this by 50 lines and you understand that I had to go 50 times in the menu instead of one*.

And this happens for many options, if I want to do a given number of object several times, the options often goes back to default between each object I draw **which is really time consuming**.

**My question: are there options to fix this ?**

A related but not identical is when I want to save in PNG. Let's assume my .svg is in the folder "folder1". If I want to export into PNG it always propose me an obscure default folder. I then have to find again my folder.

**My second question: Is there a way to force the default path of PNG being the same as where the SVG I am working on is ?** I am not asking to specify a default folder for PNG save but to "attach" the folder it saves in to where the SVG currently is.

Comment: Please don't ask 2 questions, even if related, in one. Why should I repeat Billy Kerr's answer in mine, if I only have an answer for your 2nd question? Which would you accept, given my answer was good (it isn't very good) for q2? Accepting an answer or not gives a wrong impression either way, if only one part is answered.You may link from one q. to the other, if the relation is relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *Edit > Preferences > Tools*, go through the tools you want to use, selecting "Last used Style" for each.

[image]

As for your second question, as far as I know, I don't think it's possible.